# How to create custom field with labels field-llike behavior in JIRA?

Tags: jira, custom-fields

I want to create a custom field with a set of values. Set should be filled by users.
It should work like standard "Labels" field, but use other set of values.
Is any way to do so in JIRA 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom fields of type Labels and the labels for that field only appear in that one custom field.